# The Chinese cuisine appeals to gourmets

Tags: meaning

Which one is correct?

A. The Chinese cuisine appeals to **gourmets at home and abroad**.

B. The Chinese cuisine appeals to **gourmets from home and abroad**.

Comment: Where did these sentences come from? Did you write them? Find them in a practice test? [This meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) gives some hints on how to write questions that will be better received on this site.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you so much, J.R., for providing me with this useful information! I asked my questions in concise sentences for fear that that people will lose patience while reading my posts. Actually I did a lot of research into this question before I asked it here. Thank you for reliving me of my major concern. Perhaps this site is different from other sites. Thank you again :D

Comment: Yes, this site is proudly [a little bit different from other sites](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour). Other places might lose their patience if you are not terse and concise, but here we value thoroughness. As an example, [this is one of my favorite ELL questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118188).

Comment: @J.R. Thanks a lot for that! I will make sure I have followed all these rules before I post a question in a new post :D

Answer (score 1):

**home** *can* be deictic but it need not be, and whether it is or isn't being used in that manner, reflecting the speaker's perspective on where home is, can sometimes be ascertained by the preposition.

With "*from* home" in the examples given, home is where the speaker thinks his or her home is.

"*at* home" is ambiguous. The speaker *might* mean "here at home" with "at home" but might not.  So we often say "here" to disambiguate: "*here* at home".

*People from home and abroad like this music*. => People here in this land and people in other lands like this music.

*Some people are impolite at home and abroad.*  => 
 a) Some people are impolite whether they are in their own lands or traveling. b) Some people are impolite here in this land and in other lands.

> *Some people are impolite here at home and abroad*. => Some people are impolite here in this land and in other lands.